Align the table aliases in the JOIN clause with SQLFluff?
I'm setting up SQLFluff to lint my BigQuery SQL files, and I want to apply some customized align logic.
I've read their documentation about Aligned Elements, and have been able to align column aliases like so:
SELECT
   a           AS first_column,
   b           AS second_column,
   (a + b) / 2 AS third_column
FROM foo AS bar

What I want to do next is something similar, but for the tables and joins listed in the FROM clause. I would want to go from:
SELECT *
FROM table AS t
    LEFT JOIN table_two AS t2_alias ON t2_alias.t_id = t.id
    LEFT JOIN table_three AS t3 ON t3.t_id = t.id

to:
SELECT *
FROM table AS t
    LEFT JOIN table_two   AS t2_alias ON t2_alias.t_id = t.id
    LEFT JOIN table_three AS t3       ON t3.t_id = t.id

Is this possible?
